# Difference of two closed convex cone that does not contain (1,...,1)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Let $a_1, \dots, a_p$ be $p$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $K$ the closed convex cone generated by $(a_1, \dots, a_p)$, i.e.
$$K = \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^p \lambda_i a_i | (\lambda_i) \in \mathbb{R}^p_+ \right\}$$
Let's assume that $K\cap\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \emptyset$.

Show that (a) $K-\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is a closed convex cone (b) that does not contain $\mathbf{1} = (1, \dots, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

//
For (a),

- $K-\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is convex ($\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is convex and the sum of two convex set is convex).
- $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is closed and so is $K$ (as a cone generated by a finite number of elements of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$)

However the sum $K + (-\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ is closed only if either of the two sets is compact. Therefore I need to show that $K$ is compact, but is it the case?

For (b),
I am trying to prove by contradiction that if $\mathbf{1}$ can be written as $\mathbf{1} = k + x_+$
with $k \in K$ and $x_+ = -x_-, \: x_- \in -\mathbb{R}^n_+$
then $K\cap\mathbb{R}^n_+ \neq \emptyset$ (the contradiction).
But I cannot get there.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Are the $a_i$ arbitrary here? I don't see why we can't just say $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$, so if $\mathbf{1}\in K$ then $\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{0}\in K-\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$. In particular, it seems like this property may not always hold.

Comment: @Zim yes, $a_1, \dots, a_p$ are $p$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not sure I am following you. You cannot assume that $\mathbf{1}$ is an element of $K$. And $\mathbf{1} = (1, \dots, 1) \notin K-\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is actually what is to be shown, given that $K\cap\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \emptyset$

Comment: Oh I see, whoops I misread $=\varnothing$ for $\neq\varnothing$!
By the way, since both sets are closed, the smallest possible set for their intersection is $K\cap \mathbb{R}_{+}^n=\{0\}$. That shouldn't mess with the proof though. *hint*: If $\mathbf{1}\in K-\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$, then what can we derive about where $a_i$ reside?

Comment: thanks @Zim, $\mathbf{1} \in K + (-\mathbb{R}^n_+) \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^p \lambda_j a_j = (1+x^{+}_i)$  
where $x^{+}_i \geq 0$ for $i=1, \dots, n$  
which implies that all $a_j$ (for $j=1, \dots, p$)  must reside in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Comment: Re-(a), how can we show that sum $K-\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ is closed, since neither $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ nor $K$  is (a-priori) compact? I can at most say that $K$ is closed which is not enough to conclude on the closed property of  $K-\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ it is closed **and bounded**. *Practice Exercise:* Characterize all of the bounded cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (hint: there is only one of them!). This exercise suggests that a compactness argument probably won't work for (a). That's OK though, since closedness holds way more frequently than compactness. I'd suggest a direct proof: Consider the limit of a sequence of elements in $K-\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$, then show it resides in $K-\mathbb{R}^n_+$.